# Can I customise the confluent provided connectors?

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I want to do some customization on top of the connector provided by confluent. Can anyone guide me how can I do that?
In my use-case I am using Http sink connector (https://www.confluent.io/hub/confluentinc/kafka-connect-http). I am unable to find the git code for the same.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is under the Commercial license by Confluent, which means they are not going to make the source code available.

Comment: Helimar: Does this mean if we have licence then we can get the source code and make changes on top of it?

Comment: I don't think so